# How to exclude static property when using GetProperties method

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, static, bindingflags

I was wonder if I can exclude static property when I'm using GetProperties() to extract all the property for a specific class. I'm aware of using BindingFlags for this to filter properties what I need but what I really want is that I want to exclude static properties. I try to use something like this:

```
typeof(<class>).GetProperties(!BindingFlags.Static);
```

but I don't think it works, because VS throw me some syntax error. Here is what inside my class with properties.

```
public class HospitalUploadDtl : Base.Tables
        {
            public HospitalUploadDtl() { }
            public HospitalUploadDtl(SqlDataReader reader)
            {
                ReadReader(reader);
            }
            #region Properties
            public long BatchDtlId { get; set; }
            public long BatchNumber { get; set; }
            public string HospitalCode { get; set; }
            public string HospitalName { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public string City { get; set; }
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string ContractPerson { get; set; }
            public string ContactNo { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public bool isAccredited { get; set; }
            public bool isClinic { get; set; }
            public string FaxNo { get; set; }
            public string TypeofFacility { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
            public string Specialty { get; set; }
            public string ProviderName { get; set; }
            public bool CashlessInPatient { get; set; }
            public bool CashlessOutPatient { get; set; }
            #endregion

            public static dcHospitalUploadDtl dataCtrl;
            public static dcHospitalUploadDtl DataCtrl
            {
                get
                {
                    if (dataCtrl == null)
                        dataCtrl = new dcHospitalUploadDtl();
                    return dataCtrl;
                }
            }
        }
```

for this scenario I want to exclude "DataCtrl" property when I call for GetProperties(). Thanks for the response. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public` (if you only include `Instance`, no properties will be found since neither `Public` nor `NonPublic` are specified).

Answer (score 2):

The call

```
typeof(<class>).GetProperties(!BindingFlags.Static);
```

does not do what you expect: the value passed in to `GetProperties` is a *bit mask*, not an expression. Only bitwise ORs are allowed inside the expression. In other words, you cannot say things that you don't want: you must say which things you do want. So instead of passing `!BindingFlags.Static` you should pass `BindingFlags.Instance`.

Alternatively, you can get all properties, and then apply LINQ with its rich filtering semantic to remove the items you don't need:

```
typeof(<class>).GetProperties().Where(p => !p.GetGetMethod().IsStatic).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `BindingFlags.Instance` flag.

```
typeof(HospitalUploadDtl).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```